# Running Node, Yeoman, Grunt etc. on Ubuntu virtual server with windows host

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ubuntu, yeoman

My setup:

Windows Host machine (since I am a front-end dev, I do need many tools that just work best only on Windows)

Guest Ubuntu Server (dedicated)

**All web projects are on the host machine, shared by guest addition to Ubuntu sever (NTFS)**

Everything was working fine, but now I am at the beginning of new project that will be pure AngularJS web-app. I have researched some best structures for apps like this one, and decided to go for Yeoman Angular generator.

Unfortunately after long time spent on it and a lot of research I realized it will be impossible, since Yeoman is trying to create a lot of symbolic links, which seems in my setting impossible.

So I spent even more time researching and found another satisfactory structure - angular-app. Unfortunately, again, symbolic links once you try to install npm dependencies.

Therefore the question: Is it even possible to do development of angular app based on Yeoman Angular generator, angular-app or other great resources on Windows with virtual Ubuntu guest server? Or do I have to spend hours creating my own structure without symbolic links?

Comment: I use this setup, and do not have an issue, what problem do you have with the symlinks ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ff2mow6kzq5dqt7/log.txt is just a "few" lines of the errors I am getting... There are more and different errors, but its not that easy to extract them

Comment: After another look, it seems that the errors start when "yo angular" runs "npm install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of admin rights of windows which is not allowing to create symlinks, please follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269727/npm-errors-when-installing-packages-on-windows-share/269735#269735) link for further discussion. You can do without creating symlinks as well if that you can afford, use `npm install --no-bin-links`